# What is the idiomatic way to load an entire project into the iPython interpreter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Suppose I have an example project whose directory structure looks like the following:

- src/

  - main.py
  - dirA/

    - __init__.py
    - moduleonedira.py
    - moduletwodira.py
  - dirB/

    - __init__.py
    - moduleonedirb.py
    - moduletwodirb.py
    - modulethreedirb.py

Currently all __init__.py files are blank.

What is the best way to import all of the modules of a project into the iPython interpreter?

Currently I am importing them individually. 
I probably could instead use some sort of script as a way of automating the imports but want to know the idiomatic Python way.